# Columns into rows for correlation tables

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, correlation

I have the following datasets with score - a numeric variable - associated to multiple tag columns (tag1, tag2... Tag6).

```
Score    Tag         Tag2
56       #Sustainable #Healthcare 
45       #Health      #IT
65       #Women       #IT
```

I would like to reshape my dataset so to have a table similar to a correlation table

```
              Healthcare IT
#Sustainable  56
#Health                  45
#Women                   65
```

How? Or, is there any other way to see how the combination of the column tags relates to the scoring row?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html),

```
df.pivot_table(values='Score',
            index='Tag',
            columns='Tag2',
            aggfunc='sum',
            fill_value='')
```

Comment: It says: ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape - why? I also wanted to make clear that the values inside the tags columns repeat themselves (like #IT) and I'd like to have the unique values on rows and columns..